# C++ SFML 2.1 template error

Tags: c++

I have written a very simple class for SFML 2.1 which I'm using to handle text events, however when I'm trying to create an object using this class I'm receiving this error:

```
missing template arguments before '(' token|
```

I know very little about templates, I just know when they are used, but I have no coding experience with them. I will link more important code down there:

```
class Text
{
    public:
    sf::Font font;
    sf::Text text;
    Text(sf::Color color = sf::Color(255,255,255), sf::Vector2f position = sf::Vector2f(SCREEN_X/2,SCREEN_Y/2), int c_size=24, string s="NULL")
    {
        font.loadFromFile("Arial.ttf");
        text.setFont(font);
        text.setColor(color);
        text.setPosition(position);
        text.setCharacterSize(c_size);
        text.setString(s);
    }
};
```

Finally, instruction which is creating this error:

```
Text t1(sf::Color(255,0,0), sf::Vector2(10,10), 28, "t1");
```

What is causing this error?

Comment: Down vote for poor code formatting. Fixed in edit.

Comment: @ResidentBiscuit If it's fixed, there is no reason for the downvote

Comment: It was my edit that fixed it. I guess I could have made that more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sf::Vector2` is a template class, that is you have to provide template arguments such as `sf::Vector2<int>` or `sf::Vector2<float>`. SFML defines some typedefs to help you (and you use them). So just fix `sf::Vector2` with `sf::Vector2f` which is a typedef for `sf::Vector2<float>`.

Comment: Great thanks, the most simple things are the most dangerous for programming. Topic can be closed.

Comment: @user3817838 accept this answer if you consider it to be correct.